# Tree in doctrine / symfony with CRUD

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The major task is to have an entity, that can be connected to another one.
I already got an entity called "Dossier" and within this one I like to have a tree structure like for mails.

- Would you store a conversation in that way?
- How can I achieve a tree using Doctrine?
- Can Symfony generate the CRUD for it?

Comment: For your second question take a look at the tree doctrine extension: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md

Comment: Also take a look at this bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

I like generating annotation style, YAML as a second choice personally.  How would you be generating your entity mapping?  I believe XML is your other choice.

What your asking it seems, is can you have a relation, yes you can.  You use FK's or Foriegn Keys for this.  Have you looked into MySQL yet, or what is your interest?

If your not sure how to design your schema, there is a great program for MySQL called MySQL Workbench.  Are you familiar? You can use this to generate a simply FK table relationship, then generation of the entities will follow this.  Regenerate each time you make a readjustment of your schema.  I think reverse engineering entities from schema is the best way.

If you go this route, once you have your DB Schema designed, tables built, if empty doesnt matter, you can reverse engineer your entities this way.  [see this url here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

```
//import orm mapping information from database, and using a filter for a specific table if you wanted
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force YourBundle yml --filter Table1

//convert mapping information, only if you didnt use YML in the top command.
//we need to force this, make sure you dont need any changes on the entity page (normally this is left default_, otherwise back it up first.
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src --force --filter Table1
```

Generate the entities now

```
$php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle

// or generate an entity from scratch
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Generate your getters and setters to any new properties, wont touch your methods, safe.

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/YourBundle/Entity/Table1
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force or --dump-sql
```

This will carry over the Foriegn Relationships.  When you use Doctrine to access your data, you can query using relations how you see fit...  Ill try to get a good example on this, i do have one, but heres an example otherwise.

```
/**
 * getfruitSubtextures()
 * @Route("/fruit/subtextures/color/{color}/size/{size}/texture/{texture}", name="get_fruit_subtextures", options={"expose"=true})
 * @param $color
 * @param $size
 * @param $texture
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getfruitSubtextures($color, $size, $texture){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rsm = new ResultSetfruitpingBuilder($em);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('WeRuS\fruitBundle\Entity\Opttextures', 'g');

    $sql = "SELECT SubtextureLabel, textureSubtexture
            FROM opt_textures
            WHERE texturelabel = :texturelabel
            AND color = :color
            AND size = :size
            ORDER BY SubtextureLabel ASC";

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql,$rsm);

    $query->setParameters(array(
        'color' => $color,
        'size' => $size,
        'texturelabel' => $texture,
    ));

    $results = $query->getArrayResult();

    if (!$results)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No Matching subtextures found for this fruit size texture!');
    }
    else
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData($results);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

As far making a CRUD for it, wait until you have your schema, and entities in working order, then you follow [this procedure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html)

```
$ php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=YourBundle:Table1  --with-write --format=annotation  --overwrite
```

Edit, i thougth the user was looking for example of a tree like structure, as opposed to tree, this article primarily serves how to do it without tree.  oops.